# Ошибка при парсинге JSON на JS

Tags: javascript, json

Есть вот такой JSON (это, если важно, формула из экселя):

```
{"value":"=IF(C23=1,IF(C21=0,IF(C38=E38,CONCATENATE(TEXT(AB15,\"# ##0\"),\" - \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0432\u044b\u0435 \",W13,\" \u043c\u0435\u0441. \",\" \",),0),0),IF(C21=0,IF(C38=E38,CONCATENATE(TEXT(Z15,\"# ##0\"),\" - \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0432\u044b\u0435 \",W13,\" \u043c\u0435\u0441. \",\" \",),0),0))"}
```

При вызове JSON.parse к этому JSON возникает ошибка:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 63
```

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Это не JSON. Откуда он взялся?

Comment: Как парсите? Покажите в вопросе. У вас там есть слеши и если та строка приходит как в вопросе, то проблем не должно быть, а если она у вас такая в коде и вы пытаетесь распарсить ту строку, то экранирование в строке в коде может привести к ошибке. На питоне это парсится: https://onlinegdb.com/Hk2s2hqJa (но как писал выше нужно понимать как работает экранирование в коде)

Comment: Вернее это JSON если именно это написано в *отдельном* json-файле. Если вы пытаетесь написать это как строку в JS-файле, то получится невалидный JSON

Comment: @AlexeyTen, это JSON. Он выводится на веб-страницу с помощью
echo json_encode ($result). Просто при выводе кавычки не сохраняются, поэтому вы подумали что это не JSON?

Comment: @gil9red, есть моя функция console, написанная на php:
echo "<script>console.log (JSON.parse ('{$str}'))</script>";
В эту функцию я передаю json_ecode ($result), где $result - это тот объект, который я указал в вопросе

Comment: Как я написал выше «Если вы пытаетесь написать это как строку в JS-файле, то получится невалидный JSON». В данном случае в теге script, что по сути то же самое

Comment: @AlexeyTen, я заключаю этот массив в одинарные кавычки, перед тем как вызвать JSON.parse

Comment: Ага, но бекслеши всё-равно отрабатывают как экранирование в JS. А самое главное, вам вообще тут не нужен `JSON.parse`. Проще задать у `json_encode` флаги `JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP` и на выходе у вас будет готовый литерал объекта который не нужно парсить

Comment: @AlexeyTen, моя функция console - рабочая. Если передавать туда другие json, созданные json_encode (*какой-то php объект), все корректно работает. Проблема именно с этим конкретным JSON. В них нельзя использовать символы '#'?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, просто мне нужно, чтобы этот объект вывелся в консоль, поэтому и приходится использовать JS

Comment: @Платон, проблема не с `#`, а с слешами. Смотрите, `\"` это два символа или один? Я скажу, что зависит от контекста. Если это в коде, в строке, это будет 1 символ, просто двойная кавычка, сами попробуйте `console.log('\"'.length)`. Из-за этого у вас JSON не валиден, т.к. внутренние кавычки в значении не экранируются. Чтобы было хорошо, нужно экранировать сам слеш, т.е. `console.log('\\"'.length)`, тогда JSON увидит, что там слеш перед кавычкой и поймет, что кавычка часть строки значения. **Но раз** вы пишите из php в сам файл js этот json, то лучше писать как есть -- как объект js, без строки

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо большое! Я что-то не догадался, что этот объект можно и не парсить на JS, а просто вставить в строку кода)

Comment: @Платон, пожалуйста :) Оформите сами ответ, указав как решили проблему ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае можно не использовать функцию JSON.parse.
Объект приходит от json_encode ($array) в PHP, а console.log вызывается из тега script, который выводится в документ через echo:

```
$json = json_encode ($array, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP);
echo "<script>console.log ({$json})</script>";
```

Поэтому JSON.parse нет необходимости использовать, ведь JSON - это уже объект JS.

Comment: Ох. Добавьте экранирование которое я писал выше. А то если в `$array`  попадётся строка `</script>` то случится нежданчик.